# ipython is not recognized as an internal or external command (pyspark)

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I have installed spark the release: `spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7`.

I'm using `Windows 10` OS

My java version `1.8.0_144`

I have set my environment variables:

```
SPARK_HOME D:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7

HADOOP_HOME D:\Hadoop ( where I put bin\winutils.exe )

PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON ipython

PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS notebook
```

Path is `D:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin`

When I launch `pyspark` from command line I have this error:

```
ipython is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I tried also to set `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` in `jupyter` but and it's giving me the same error (not recognized as an internal or external command).

Any help please?

Comment: You sure have `jupyter` and `ipython` installed in your machine?

Answer (score 7):

Search in your machine the ipython application, in my case it is in "c:\Anaconda3\Scripts". Then just add that path to the PATH Environment Variables

Comment: C:\Users\user1\Anaconda3\Scripts

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 10 with Anaconda installed , please use Anaconda prompt rather that windows cmd and launch , jupyter notebook using below command

```
  pyspark --master local[2]
```

Please make sure all configurations as mentioned in question are done.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 I solved by manually adding the path in Anaconda - Windows Powershell:

`$env:Path += ";path\to\spark\bin"`

other commands such as "setx" or other commands did not work for me.

EDIT: every time I start Anaconda prompt I need to run the command above again. As soon as I manage to make this solution "definitive" I'll edit my answer.
Finally, I need to add Path to scala as well to make it work with Jupyter Notebook, with the following:

`$env:Path += ";C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin"`

Answer (score 0):

Locate IPython Installation Directory:
First, find out where IPython is installed on your system. You can use the following command in your terminal or command prompt:

pip show ipython

Look for the "Location" field in the output. It will show you the directory where IPython is installed.

Add IPython Directory to PATH:

Windows:

Open the Start menu and search for "Environment Variables."

Click on "Edit the system environment variables."

In the System Properties window, click the "Environment Variables..." button.

In the Environment Variables window, find the "Path" variable in the "System variables" section and click "Edit."

Click "New" and add the path to the directory where IPython is installed.

Click "OK" to close each window.

Linux/macOS:

Open your terminal and edit the shell configuration file. This is usually ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, or ~/.zshrc.

Add the following line at the end of the file, replacing /path/to/ipython with the actual path you found in step 1:

export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/ipython
Save the file and either restart your terminal or run source ~/.bashrc (or the respective file for your shell) to apply the changes.

Verify PATH Changes:
Open a new terminal window and type:

bash

ipython
If everything is configured correctly, this should now launch IPython.

Remember to replace /path/to/ipython with the actual path where IPython is installed on your system.