# 'ipython' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, ipython

I installed IPython using the command in the terminal
`pip install IPython`.

After successful installation I tried to run `ipython` using the command and found the following:

`C:\Users\acer>ipython`

got an **error**:

`'ipython' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

IPython files are located in this directory:

`C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\IPython`

I am a beginner to ipython, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ipython is not recognized as an internal or external command (pyspark)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47364535/ipython-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-pyspark)

Comment: Try changing capital letters or using `python IPython` or `python -m IPython`

Comment: @MrJavy, i tried everything and got this everytime                                                 python: can't open file 'ipython': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Have you tried installing `Jupyter`?

Comment: Try python -m IPython